# Using table information inside a WHERE clause

Tags: sql

So some background for this question. I have created a query that looks checks SCCM for every piece of software given single machine. So I have my statement:

```
SELECT Programs.DisplayName, Programs.Publisher etc..
FROM my_db
WHERE machine_Name = @computername
```

Above is just an example of what I do. The point is that this query returns a list of software that is in SCCM for that single machine.

Now my issue is that I have been given a massive list of machines to find software for.

What I want to do is to somehow make a single query that will take in a list of machines and return results for every name in that list (which is like 300 lines).

I am trying to see if it is possible to make a table with the list of machine names and use that table in my `WHERE` clause. Is this something that cannot be done in SQL alone or is this possible?

I know you can use comma delimited arrays in `WHERE` clauses but there are so many names that I am not sure that will work.

Comment: An array with 300 elements? Sure it will work. I've did this with more than 2000 items, still works.

Comment: Well that awesome to hear! For some reason I was under the impression that where has a restriction on how many items you can use in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the list of machines in a separate table is a *good idea*. While it is doable to build a long list of values that you can use on the right side of the `IN` operator, using a reference table is more scalable (lists are limited to a few thousands elements), and easier to maintain.

Once you have this table created and filled, you can just join it with your table. Assuming that your reference table is called `machines` and has a column named `machine`, this would look like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM programs p
INNER JOIN machines m ON m.machine_name = p.machine_name
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot for not even considering that I wouldn't need to use the table as an "input" since its literally going to be joined. Its like I had the answer all along. Thanks @GMB